# Breaking list into nested list by some specific pattern in python

Tags: python, list, jupyter-notebook

I have list like mentioned below where 'T0000XXX' is transaction id there, 'IXXX' is the item list, and the number of those items are completely random, like first transaction has 5 items, second has 2 items, third has 9 items likewise, and the last element is the sum of amount of items.

And this list contains > 100k elements

```
['T0000093', 'I717', 'I491', 'I82', 'I345', 'I423', 2469.0,
 'T0000166', 'I4', 'I425', 3534.0,
 'T0000256', 'I558', 'I325', 'I242', 'I523', 'I568', 'I207', 'I137', 'I15', 'I477', 8467.0]
```

So i want to break this list into nested list where the sublist list will have 3 attributes, transaction-id, number of items and amount, like this

```
[['T0000093', 'I717', 'I491', 'I82', 'I345', 'I423', 2469.0],
 ['T0000166', 'I4', 'I425', 3534.0],
 ['T0000256', 'I558', 'I325', 'I242', 'I523', 'I568', 'I207', 'I137', 'I15', 'I477', 8467.0]]
```

Comment: I have a way using exec, should I post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

```
lst = ['T0000093', 'I717', 'I491', 'I82', 'I345', 'I423', 2469.0, 'T0000166', 'I4', 'I425', 3534.0, 'T0000256', 'I558', 'I325', 'I242', 'I523', 'I568', 'I207', 'I137', 'I15', 'I477', 8467.0]

result = [[]]  # start with sublist
for i, item in enumerate(lst):
  result[-1].append(item) # add to last sublist
  if isinstance(item, float) and i < len(lst)-1:
    # Start new sublist since on float and not last item in lst
    result.append([])

print(result)
# Output: [['T0000093', 'I717', 'I491', 'I82', 'I345', 'I423', 2469.0], ['T0000166', 'I4', 'I425', 3534.0], ['T0000256', 'I558', 'I325', 'I242', 'I523', 'I568', 'I207', 'I137', 'I15', 'I477', 8467.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a fancy way to do this via comprehension, but I think the simplest option is going to be to build the list up iteratively:

```
from typing import List, Union

flat_list: List[Union[str, float]] = ['T0000093', 'I717', 'I491', 'I82', 'I345', 'I423', 2469.0, 'T0000166', 'I4', 'I425', 3534.0, 'T0000256', 'I558', 'I325', 'I242', 'I523', 'I568', 'I207', 'I137', 'I15', 'I477', 8467.0]
nested_list: List[List[Union[str, float]]] = []
sub_list: List[Union[str, float]] = []
for item in flat_list:
    if isinstance(item, str) and item.startswith("T"):
        sub_list = []
        nested_list.append(sub_list)
    sub_list.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every Transaction is starting with a 'T'. You can use this to break the list into the nested list. The code will look like this:

```
L=['T0000093', 'I717', 'I491', 'I82', 'I345', 'I423', 2469.0, 'T0000166', 'I4', 'I425', 3534.0, 'T0000256', 'I558', 'I325', 'I242', 'I523', 'I568', 'I207', 'I137', 'I15', 'I477', 8467.0]

nested_list=[]
List=[]
for x in L:
    if(len(List)==0):
        List.append(x)
    elif(type(x)==str and x[0]=='T'):
        nested_list.append(List)
        List=[]
        List.append(x)
    else:
        List.append(x)
if(len(List)!=0):
    nested_list.append(List)
print(nested_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start = 0
nested = []
your_list = your_list[::-1]

for i in range(len(your_list)):
    if str(your_list[i]).startswith('T'):
        nested.append(your_list[start:i])
        start = i

# [[], ['T0000093', 'I717', 'I491', 'I82', 'I345', 'I423', 2469.0], ['T0000166', 'I4', 'I425', 3534.0], ['T0000256', 'I558', 'I325', 'I242', 'I523', 'I568', 'I207', 'I137', 'I15', 'I477', 8467.0]]
```

remove the empty at last